# как хранить терабайты данных в rest api на java

Tags: java

У меня есть большое количество данных и rest api. Эта апишка должна уметь загружать файл и отдавать его. Ну это понятно как сделать. Вопрос в том как и где хранить эти файлы. Локально их хранить на машине или на другом хосте ? по сути обработки как таковой и нет они просто раздаются как ресурс.У меня недостаточно опыта в разработке хотел бы узнать у старших коллег. Я сам думаю сделать так. Несколько жестких смонтировать в одну директорию и уже туда загружать файлы. И это решение мне кажется крайне сомнительным

Comment: Да хоть в неразмеченой области диска храните :) вот так абстрактно подсказать файловую систему не зная задачи - сложно и холиварно ;)

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Comment: Фильмы хранить надо и отдавать пользователям. Тоесть контроллер принимает файл(фильм) и отдает его в виде ресурса. Вопрос в том где хранить этим фильмы

Answer (score 1):

Это довольно известная проблема.

Если говорить о стоимости-то, как ни странно, ничего дешевле "домашнего хостинга" не придумано. Любое облако начинает стоить существенных денег, стОит только выйти за пределы типичного объема или типичных требований к процессору.

Технически сейчас любой провайдер интернета не может сделать ничего, чтобы запретить Вам раздавать контент с домашнего компа. Ну, по крайней мере, пока этот контент не нарушает закон явно. Иначе- полетят абузы, и Вас довольно быстро могут отключить.

Правда, провайдеры вертятся, как уж на сковородке, и сейчас у домашнего хостинга есть следующие проблемы:

1. ограниченная полоса канала на отдачу. Около 100-200 мегабит. На тарифах с большей пропускной способностью, как правило, есть ограничения по трафику
2. серый ip или белый, но динамический. Это проблема, решается либо покупкой выделенного ip, либо динамическим dns- в общем, нужно думать уже в каждом конкретном случае.
3. блокировки портов 80, 443 и т.п., привычных для размещения сайта. Я не зря написал "привычных": в принципе, сайт будет работать и на других портах. Это можно решить так: в облаке находятся легковесные странички, а ссылки на сами файлы ведут уже на домашний сервер.

Если Вы хотите вникнуть в тему поподробнее-я бы начал с dns-серверов и с настройки nginx . Мне кажется, если эти две темы немного "покопать" - то ясности, подходит ли размещение на домашнем хостинге файлов для Вашего проекта -станет намного больше.

Иногда, когда смотришь на цены чего то типа Авс глассир кажется, что это очень дёшево. Но не забывайте, что цены типа "1 цент за гигабайт" - это цены за хранение. Как только Вы захотите скачать эти данные из хранилища-ценник взлетит до небес. Вообще, взлет цен до небес-это фирменная черта облачных решений Амазона.

Задавайте вопросы в комментариях, постараюсь ответить!

Comment: нет нет , дело не в хосте. Дело в том как правильно нужно хранить такой объем данных. Я просто беру записываю их на диск и все на этом. Потом просто читаю нужный файл и отдаю его в виде ресурса. Такой подход он нормальный ? вот об этом я ) я так еще не делал и вот гнетут сомнения по такому решению) в винде я сделал так в админку поместил возможность выбирать путь куда будет загружен файл а ПО уже сканирует и ищет на каком диске файл. Плюс я могу получать информацию о свободном пространстве на диске. В люнексе так не работает вот

Comment: А, ну тогда все просто. Подход-правильный. И про свободное пространство легко можно узнать, сколько его, есть у меня простой пример программы, которая это делает. Но я бы отдельной таблицей в базе данных хранил связь между "сущностью" (фильмом) и путем в файловой системе. Это даёт определенную гибкость

Comment: супер тогда. Спасибо Вам больше за потраченное время

Comment: Что если один из жёстких помрёт?

Comment: Классическим ответом на "что, если диск умрет?" Является хранение с избыточностью. Либо raid, либо, более современно-ZFS

Comment: Вспомнил! Для RHEL - линейки систем есть еще такая прикольная FS, работающая в user space - Stratis. Можете поиграться!